# Redux DevTools are sometimes disabled

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, redux-devtools-extension

I am developing app using Angular 5 + NgRx. I have the browser extension Redux DevTools installed (for both Chrome and Firefox). But both extensions are disabled (icon is gray and does not show store history)

My app has several modules, which are loaded asynchronously.
The main app.module.ts contains this code

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
 user: userReducer
})
```

and the other module has this

```
StoreModule.forFeature('dashboard', dashboardReducer),
StoreModule.forFeature('globalSettings', globalSettingsReducer),
StoreModule.forFeature('userInfo', userSettingsReducer),
```

The result is that the Redux DevTools extension is disabled. No related error reported in the console whatsoever. What am I doing wrong? I can't get it to work and I am getting frustrated.

When I changed it to this (obviously wrong) code, then interestingly DevTools started to work again, but other things broke (as expected)

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
 'dashboard': dashboardReducer,
 'globalSettings': globalSettingsReducer,
 'userInfo': userSettingsReducer
}),
```

I do need the DevTools to work, because it helps me to better thing/visualize the current state of the app. Also without Redux DevTools and time traveling debugging, the whole Redux approach seems to me like writing too much boilerplate. When the tooling ecosystem works, then it is great, but when it breaks, then all I have is more boilerplate code (reducers, actions, etc).

Why Redux DevTools wont start?
Why doesn't it report any error to console?
How to make it work again?

PS: I am not using the npm package for Redux DevTools, I am using the raw store as provided by @ngrx/store. It used to work fine, until I've added the .forFeature() call.

Please advice

Comment: What does your redux create store function look like?

Comment: As I've said I don't create store, I just import it from @ngrx/store and then add store.select(whatever), store.dispatch() etc

Comment: Well are you using store-devtools? https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store-devtools/README.md

Comment: I am not. Is that a requirement? It used to work without it just fine...

Comment: sorry. my bad, I am using it (I am just one of the developers, it has been added by someone else) `...(environment.reduxDevTools ? [StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25 })] : [])`

Comment: and  the variable `environment.reduxDevTools` is set to `true`

Comment: Ok cool just checking the obvious things. When it's not showing next time also check that `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` is defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165895/discussion-between-david-votrubec-and-dominic-tobias).

Answer (score 3):

Aaaah, so the solution is to initialize StoreDevtoolsModule in the MAIN module (usually called app.module). If you initialize it in some other module, which is loaded later, then it will behave in absurdly weird ways (see my original question)

So the solution was to move `StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25 })` from async loaded module to the main app.module. After that it works like a charm again.

But for me, as a newbie on this project, when the DevTools has already been setup before, it was totally not obvious, why it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Something of note that has caught me up from time to time is that the load order matters in your app.module too.

The `StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 50 }),` module must always come after the `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),` module in your `app.module.ts` imports or the same thing will happen as has been happening to you.